Can I use more high-fidelity render in drake
I want to use drake to collect machine-learning training data, can I use more high-fidelity render in drake?

You have a couple of options:

The RenderEngineVtk can be configured to render using PBR with environment and shadow-casting lights. This is still raster based -- i.e., no path tracing or global illumination. But it's basically interactive rates.
The RenderEngineGltfClient can be used in conjunction with  drake-blender to pass the Drake scene to a blender session that will render it using arbitrary Blender rendering configurations (for producing renderings as good as you can coax out of Blender). Depending on the size of the scene and your configuration of Blender, this can take seconds to minutes per frame.

